# Put two Excel formulas together

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have some particular data in sheet1 and some other data in sheet2.

I need to compare a specific value(Var1) from sheet1 and return a specific value from the sheet2, and return an output for the same. I successfully did that with this formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A, A2), "Yes", "No")
```

Sheet1

```
+------+------+---------+---------+
| var1 | var2 | result1 | result2 |
+------+------+---------+---------+
|      |      |         |         |
| abc  |  123 | yes     | yes     |
|      |      |         |         |
| bcd  |  234 | yes     | no      |
|      |      |         |         |
| cde  |  456 | no      | blank   |
+------+------+---------+---------+
```

Sheet2

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| List1 | List2 | List3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| abc   |   123 |       |
| bcd   |       | 123   |
| def   |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I need to lookup var1 in list1, and var2 in list2 and list3

I want to compare another value(Var2) in Sheet2, only if the previous result is "Yes", which can be easily achieved with an IF function; but the catch is that it should compare values only from specific rows of Sheet2, which should be plus(+) and minus(-) 2 rows from where Var1 was found in Sheet2.

I am not proficient in VBA, but I have been trying my hand at Excel formulas.

Comment: Please, consider adding into question a piece of data you have (both for sheet 1 and sheet2). Then, select one specific cell in sheet1 and give 1 example about how the output should be in the end.

Comment: How many times the value of A2 can appear in Sheet2 ? Also, is it that +/- 2 rows from var1 should be the look_up_range for your 2nd criteria ?

Comment: @AndreSilva Included an example

Comment: @666bytes A2 is the key of the sheet and is unique in both.

Comment: @666bytes Yes. +/- 2 rows from var1 should be the look_up_range for your 2nd criteria

Comment: Quick clarification: result1 is "find var1 in List1, then compare var2 to List2 in that specific row", right? And if you do find a match for that, you want to check +/- 2 rows in List3 for var2, which would be result2?

Comment: Or is result1 simply "var1 exists in List1", with no relation to var2 at all?

Comment: @CollinGrady result1 is "var1 exists in List1", with no relation to var2 at all.

Comment: @CollinGrady And if result1 is yes, then compare var2 in List2 and List3 from Sheet2 within two rows where var1 was found in Sheet2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fun to puzzle through :)

Using your example, I placed this function in `C2` (under 'result1'), and array-filled it down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,A2),"Yes","No")
```

And for `D2` under 'result2':

```
=IF(C2="No","No",IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet2!C"&MAX((MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A)-2),1)&":C"&(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A)+2)),B2),"Yes","No"))
```

Again, array fill it down, and it should work :)

Comment: Works like a charm!!! Thanks!! Learned a lot!!

Comment: Nicely done. I try to avoid indirect when possible, though, since you'll have to update your formula when, say, inserting a column to the left or renaming your worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR() and compare if you have plus and minus. Something like this:

```
=IF(OR(A1="+";A1="-");"Ok";"")
```

Then you can change "Ok" for you formula.

```
=IF(OR(A1="+";A1="-");=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:C, A2), "Yes", "No");"")
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: My question was pretty vague, sorry bout that. Edited it for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`=IF(C2<>"Yes","",IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(Sheet2!$B$1:$C$5,MAX(0,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)-3),0),B2)>0,"Yes","No"))`

I'm assuming that:

- `var1` is a unique key, as you said.  Otherwise this will match only the first occurrence.
- You want to match `var2` in *both* `list1` and `list2`. Otherwise, you should narrow the search window to `$B$1:$B$5`.  If there are more lists to the right, just add columns to the search window.

Let me know if you have any questions about how this works.

Comment: Works like a charm!!! Thanks!! Learned a lot!!